# Link poco static library to target in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, poco-libraries

I read a lot of post but I don't yet well understood how to link my target to a static version of a library.

My project depends on poco libraries and, while in linux they are stored in /usr/local/lib (both the static and shared versions) in my windows machine are in d:\libs\poco\lib and d:\libs\poco\bin (where I have an enviroment variable called POCO_DIR = D:\libs\poco)

So, how can I have to write the find_library() directive in cmake file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never link with a Poco DLL on windows, not even when you use shared Poco libraries. Linking is always with entries in the %POCO_BASE%/lib. For shared builds, .lib is just a stub ("import library") that takes care of loading the DLL at runtime. See [Linking Implicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14wsce5.aspx) for details on how this works.

Poco static libraries can be distinguished from the import libraries for DLLs by the file name - static libs have "mt" ("mtd" for debug binaries, "md" and "mdd" when runtime library DLLs are used) appended to the name. So the import library for PocoFoundation.dll will be named PocoFoundation.lib, while the static library using static runtimes is named PocoFoundationmt.lib. Static library using dynamic runtimes is PocoFoundationmd.lib. See [Use Run-Time Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx) for details.

As for CMake, I am not an expert, but for e.g. static Foundation and Net libraries should be something like this:

```
FIND_LIBRARY(Poco_LIBRARIES NAMES PocoFoundationmt PocoNetmt PATH_SUFFIXES ${POCO_DIR}/lib)
```

EDIT: If you define POCO_STATIC in your project, static linking will be automatic through library headers, see e.g. [Foundation.h](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/include/Poco/Foundation.h#L68).

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the reply. I know how linking works :) My doubt is only which name I have to use in FIND_LIBRARY(). If in Windows there is the suffix to distinguish between various kind of builds, in Linux there is the extension only (.a or .so). So if I write 'PocoFoundationmt' maybe is valid only for Windows. I'm asking myself is there a way to use the same directive both for every systems.

Comment: Use if(WIN32) to detect the OS.